# Run Script in Google Sheets without Activating Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that uses IMPORTHTML to pull information from a table into a worksheet called "Data". On a separate worksheet I run some calculations and display results. I have a macro that deletes the contents of the cell with the IMPORTHTML and pastes in the formula again so that it can reload. I have it set to run the script "on edit" so that I can use a checkbox to update the data on demand from my results worksheet.

However, when I push the button to refresh, or when I make changes to a cell, the macro causes the worksheet that is being displayed to change due to the getActive code in the macro.

Is there a way for me to have the macro run without it activating the "Data" worksheet?

BTW - I am a complete novice at this stuff so hopefully I am explaining it all correctly.

Here is my code:

```
function Refresh1() {
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  sheetName.getRange('A8').activate();
  sheetName.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  sheetName.getActiveRange().setFormula('=IMPORTHTML("URL","table",0)');
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Results'), true);
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Refresh1() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Data!A8');
  range.clearContent();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  range.setFormula('=importhtml("URL", "table", 0)');
}
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly!